# Pass Javascript data from one function to another

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to get an image file and post it using http in angular. Angular does not model files so I need a separate function to grab the data.

How can I pass data from this function to my http request?

```
var f = document.getElementById('imageFile').files[0],
    r = new FileReader();
r.onloadend = function(e){
  var data = e.target.result;
  //***********************************************
  // This is where my data is
  //***********************************************

}
r.readAsArrayBuffer(f);

var request = $http({
  method: "post",
  url: "/data/addToStore.php",
  data: {
    product_code: $scope.product_code,
    product_name: $scope.product_name,
    autoship_price: $scope.autoship_price,
    regular_price: $scope.regular_price,
    product_category_main: $scope.product_category_main,
    product_desc: $scope.product_desc,
    cat: $scope.cat,
    /* ********************************************
    This is where I need to get my data to
    imageFile: $SOMETHING
       ********************************************  */
  },
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
});
```

Comment: Just store the data in a global variable, which will then be available in the second function.

Comment: I'd rather not put it in a global variable. Since it's an image file it can be quite big. I was looking for a way to pass it without doing that. I'm not that familiar with javascript, so I'm not sure if its possible.

Comment: You have two functions, let we say `foo()` and `bar()`. Ok!, so if you want pass the data from `bar()` to `foo()`, make `bar()` return a value, then call `bar()` from `foo()`.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment above:

```
var fileData = null;
var f = document.getElementById('imageFile').files[0],
    r = new FileReader();
r.onloadend = function(e){
  fileData = e.target.result;
  //***********************************************
  // This is where my data is
  //***********************************************

}
r.readAsArrayBuffer(f);

var request = $http({
  method: "post",
  url: "/data/addToStore.php",
  data: {
    product_code: $scope.product_code,
    product_name: $scope.product_name,
    autoship_price: $scope.autoship_price,
    regular_price: $scope.regular_price,
    product_category_main: $scope.product_category_main,
    product_desc: $scope.product_desc,
    cat: $scope.cat,
    imageFile: fileData
  },
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could refactor that into a method callback on the scope object:

```
$scope.getFile = function (){
    var f = document.getElementById('imageFile').files[0];
    var r = new FileReader();
    r.onloadend = function(e){
        var data = e.target.result;
    }
    return r.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
}

var request = $http({
  method: "post",
  url: "/data/addToStore.php",
  data: {
    product_code: $scope.product_code,
    product_name: $scope.product_name,
    autoship_price: $scope.autoship_price,
    regular_price: $scope.regular_price,
    product_category_main: $scope.product_category_main,
    product_desc: $scope.product_desc,
    cat: $scope.cat,
    fileData: $scope.getFile()
  },
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing here. This would just add data to the scope so I can display in in my app? Right? What I need to do is upload the image to an S3 bucket. Would this help do that?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question, so edited it.  You are trying to get an image you already have on the client to the server, right?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am looking for. I tried something like that but I couldn't make it work. In your code `var getFile = function {` needed to be modified to `var getFile = function() {` to work. But that just assigned the text of the entire function to getFile. And also `fileData: getFile()` calls a function which doesn't exist. If I change it to `function getFile() {` no value is passed into `fileData:` I also tried assigning it to a variable. `var getFile = function getFile() {` then `fileData: getFile` also doesn't pass any value.

Comment: I didn't run the code, so it had syntax errors.  You should be able to bind the function you need to the scope object.  I've edited the answer with the proposed changes.

Comment: You could also use an inline function: fileData: function() {/* get the file */}